# Extracting help from text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have below text and I want to obtain certain parts from it.

```
Checkbox[Skip Transfer]: Skip the transfer process if checked.

Dropdown[OS Types]:     A dropdown to select the target OS. Transfer protocol,
                        connection protocol and destination path will be adjusted
                        based on this option.
                            * Destination path may be changed manually. If it was
                              changed this option has no effect on destination.
Dropdown[CPU Types]:    A dropdown to select the executable. Target file will be
                        adjusted based on this option.
                            * Source file may be changed manually. If it was
                              changed this option has no effect.
Dropdown[Copy Actions]: A dropdown to select the action that will be applied on the
                        destination file.
```

This is my help message and I want to pass related parts to the related items.

`Checkbox[Skip Transfer]: Skip the transfer process if checked.`
For this line, **Checkbox** is my type, **Skip Transfer** is my text and **Skip the transfer process if checked.** is my help message for related item.

I tried following regex(in Python):
`(?P<kind>\w+)\[(?P<name>[\w ]+)\].*:\s+(?P<help_msg>[\w\W]*)(?!(\w+\[))`

The **kind** and the **name** parsed successfully but I couldn't get the help message correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
(?P<kind>\w+)\[(?P<name>[\w ]+)\].*:\s+(?P<help_msg>(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\w+\[))*)
```

As *help message* I'm getting

- all the characters that are not linebreaks AND
- linebreaks that are not followed by your pattern `\w+\[`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KCVBdR/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat all the lines using `.*` instead of `[\w\W]*` and then assert that it does not start with `\w+\[` after matching a newline.

You could prevent some backtracking making use of a negated character class to match until the first occurrence of the colon using `[^:]*:`

```
(?P<kind>\w+)\[(?P<name>[\w ]+)][^:]*:\s+(?P<help_msg>.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w+\[).*)*)
```

In parts

- `(?P<kind>\w+)` Named group *kind*, match 1+ word chars
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?P<name>[\w ]+)` Named group *name*, match 1+ times either   or a word char
- `][^:]*:\s+` match `]`, then 0+ times any char except `:` and then match `:` followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?P<help_msg>` Named group *help_msg*

  - `.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w+\[).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `\w+\[`
- `)` Close group `help_msg`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9yStV/1)

**Edit**

The version without the negated character class that worked for the OP

```
(?P<kind>\w+)\[(?P<name>[\w ]+)].*:\s+(?P<help_msg>.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w+\[).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rdUCB9/1)

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is almost perfect just I have to replace `[^:]*` to `.*` to work this regex rest of the text.